# Как растянуть фоновое изображение по всему размеру виджета в QT?

Tags: qt, c++

Как растянуть фоновое изображение по всему размеру виджета? При нижеописанном добавлении
"вырывается" левый верхний угол изображения. А необходимо его растянуть пропорционально размерам виджета. Можно ли сделать это, не прибегая к CSS?

```
class WidgetLoading: public QWidget
{
private:
    QBrush *brush;
    QPalette *palette;
    QImage *image;
public:
    WidgetLoading();
    ~WidgetLoading();
};

WidgetLoading::WidgetLoading(): QWidget()
{
 brush = new QBrush;
 palette = new QPalette;
 image = new QImage(":/fon.jpg");
 this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
 brush->setTextureImage(*image);
 palette->setBrush(QPalette::Window, *brush);
 this->setPalette(*palette);
}

WidgetLoading::~WidgetLoading()
{
 delete brush;
 delete palette;
 delete image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `QImage::resized()`

Comment: QImage::scaled(). Смотря какая версия